# Scala BeanProperty use custom setter

Tags: scala, javabeans

how can I define a my own setter to be used for BeanProperty in scala?

```
class Person {
    @BeanProperty var name = ""

    def name_= (newName: String): Unit = {
       name = newName.toLowerCase
    }
}
```

When I do something like this, compiler shows two conflicting setters one generated by BeanProperty and other written in code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it would work this way. Instead, you could try

```
  case class Person(var name: String) {
      def setName(s: String) {name = s} 

    }
```

An Alternate approach would be:

```
private var name = ""

    def setName(name: Name) { 
      this. name = name 
    }
```

I figured this way around getting BeanProperty kinda thing.Hope it helps.